The analogy between choosing an origin for a torsor and choosing a basis for a vector space
If we have a $G$-torsor — a space $X$ on which a group $G$ acts freely and transitively — selecting a specific element $x$ in the space as the "origin" allows us, of course, to identify $X$ with $G$. In the specific context of linear algebra, choosing an origin enables us to identify the points of an affine space with the elements of the vector space that acts on it.
If we start with the vector space $V$, of dimension $n$ over $F$, choosing a basis allows us to identify $V$ with $F^n$. The analogy with the situation above is clear — the selection of an element of a certain kind is equivalent to choosing a specific isomorphism between a structure with greater symmetry (the vector space) and a more rigid counterpart ($F^n$).
However, the current situation does not exactly fit into the framework of torsors, because $F^n$ does not naturally act on $V$.
So, what is the standard algebraic framework that generalizes both cases?

Would you consider the following example to also fit your description: "given a finite set $S$ with cardinality $n$, a choice of total order on $S$ is equivalent to a choice of isomorphism $S \simeq [n]$"? If so, I think this question and answers are relevant reading.

Perhaps you mean to be thinking of the following example: The space $Fr(V)$ of ordered bases ("frames") on $V$ is a $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$-torsor. The choice of a particular basis gives an identification of $Fr(V)$ with $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$. I'm not sure what analogy you're refering to in the title, but they seem like different things to me (if superficially similiar). Choosing an orgin for a torsor gives it extra structure. Choosing a basis for a vector space does not grant extra structure---rather it's a tool to coordinatize and do computations.
